# Are there any alignment guarantees for exception memory allocated through the Itanium ABI?

Tags: c++

The Itanium ABI states that memory for an exception is obtained by calling `__cxa_allocate_exception(size)`. What is the alignment guarantee of the returned memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Section 1.2 in chapter 4](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/abi-eh-1.21.html#base-data) says:

> The unwind interface uses a pointer to an exception header object as its representation of an exception being thrown. In general, the full representation of an exception object is language- and implementation-specific, but it will be prefixed by a header understood by the unwind interface, defined as follows:

followed by a definition of `struct _Unwind_Exception`, followed by:

> An `_Unwind_Exception` object must be double-word aligned.

As this is a *prefix* to the exception object at large, the entire block of memory must be double-word aligned.

Arguably this text does not prohibit arbitrary padding found *before* the `_Unwind_Exception`, but if this is taken to be the case then the answer is that there is no alignment guarantee whatsoever; I choose to interpret this as a minor wording defect instead.